# Pandas -- create ranks for diffrent records that similar except one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, rank

I want to fetch  1 record from duplicate rows in Df except one column. example :

| index | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | abc | efg | hij | op |
| 1 | abc | efg | hij | ki |
| 2 | abc | efg | hij | tf |
| 3 | abc | efg | hij | ge |
| 4 | xyz | mmm | qt | aa |
| 5 | xyz | mmm | qt | bb |
| 6 | xyz | mmm | qt | cc |

(order by col4 asc)
Thus, desired result could be like

| index | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | abc | efg | hij | op | 1 |
| 1 | abc | efg | hij | ki | 2 |
| 2 | abc | efg | hij | tf | 3 |
| 3 | abc | efg | hij | ge | 4 |
| 4 | xyz | mmm | qt | aa | 1 |
| 5 | xyz | mmm | qt | bb | 2 |
| 6 | xyz | mmm | qt | cc | 3 |

The goal is to obtain a rank for each similar result to fetch data as
df = df[df['rank'] == 1]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby(df.columns.difference(['col4']).tolist()).cumcount().add(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

ansev's answers does the job but for those of you who like the rank method two things might be worth trying. Unfortunately, [pandas.groupby.rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank) does only work for one column but this case that might be enough.
I confess, the case for multiple columns is a little bit busy...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'col1':['abc','abc','abc','abc','xyz','xyz','xyz'],
'col2':['efg','efg','efg','efg','mmm','mmm','mmm'],
'col3':['hij','hij','hij','hij','qt','qt','qt'],
'col4':['op','ki','tf','ge','aa','bb','cc']
})

df['rank_single_column'] = df.groupby('col3')['col4'].rank(method='first').astype(int)

df['rank_multiple_columns'] = df.groupby(df[df.columns.difference(['col4']).tolist()].apply(tuple,axis=1))['col4'].rank(method='first').astype(int)
```

An advandage of rank (not asked in the question) would be the possibility to sort for the 'col4'. This could also be achieved by adding sort_values() into ansev's answer.

```
df['rank'] = df.sort_values(['col4'],ascending=True).groupby(df.columns.difference(['col4']).tolist()).cumcount().add(1)
```